# Matrix representations of linear transformations equal over different bases

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Edit: thanks to Jim's answer and comments I think that I managed to solve the problem.

The question goes like:

> Let $S,T: \ F^3\to F^3$ be liner transformations defined by $$S(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3)=(0,\alpha_1,\alpha_2) \qquad T(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3)=(\alpha_2,\alpha_3,0)$$
>   Prove that there are bases $B$ and $C$, such that $[S]_B=[T]_C$.

Let $B$ be the standard basis of $F^3$, hence $B=\left\{\left(\begin{matrix}1\\0\\0\end{matrix}\right),\left(\begin{matrix}0\\1\\0\end{matrix}\right),\left(\begin{matrix}0\\0\\1\end{matrix}\right)\right\}$.

Using the definition of $S$: $$\displaystyle \small S(1,0,0)=(0,1,0)=\left(\begin{matrix}0\\1\\0\end{matrix}\right)_B \ ; \ S(0,1,0)=(0,0,1)=\left(\begin{matrix}0\\0\\1\end{matrix}\right)_B \ ; \ S(0,0,1)=(0,0,0)=\left(\begin{matrix}0\\0\\0\end{matrix}\right)_B$$
Thus, $\displaystyle [S]_B=\left(\begin{matrix}0&0&0\\1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{matrix}\right)$.

Now, let $C=\left\{v_1,v_2,v_3\right\}$. We know that we want $T(v_3)=\left(\begin{matrix}0\\0\\0\end{matrix}\right)_C$, hence $v_3=\left(\begin{matrix}1\\0\\0\end{matrix}\right)$. Next we want $T(v_2)=\left(\begin{matrix}0\\0\\1\end{matrix}\right)_C=v_3=\left(\begin{matrix}1\\0\\0\end{matrix}\right)$, hence $v_2=\left(\begin{matrix}0\\1\\0\end{matrix}\right)$. Finally, $T(v_1)=\left(\begin{matrix}0\\1\\0\end{matrix}\right)_C=v_2=\left(\begin{matrix}0\\1\\0\end{matrix}\right)$, hence $v_1=\left(\begin{matrix}0\\0\\1\end{matrix}\right)$ and $$[T]_C=\left(\begin{matrix}0&0&0\\1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{matrix}\right)=[S]_B$$
As required.

Comment: The matrices $[S]_B$ and $[T]_C$ are wrong. You put the image vectors $S(b_1)\dots S(b_3)$ into the matrix, which is wrong. The correct way would be to put the coordinates of $S(b_1)\dots S(b_3)$ in the matrix.

Comment: For this problem, you can experiment with standard basis vectors.

Comment: @daw, can you show an example of one vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $[S]_B$ and $[T]_C$ are incorrect.  They take, as input, a vector in the bases $B$ and $C$ but as output they give a vector in the standard basis.  So for example $[S]_B$ sends $x = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ to $y = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ \beta_1 \\ \beta_2 \end{bmatrix}$ and while $x$ represents the first basis element in the $B$ basis, $y$ is the image of that first basis element expressed in the standard basis, not in the $B$ basis.

Instead of trying to set up a big system of equations and solve it for a unique answer (the answer is not unique by a long shot) instead try thinking about what $S$ and $T$ do.  Each kills one vector and rearranges the other two.  Why not choose bases so that what's killed and what's rearranged line up?

Further hint: For the bases $B$ and $C$ you can just choose a new ordering of the standard basis for $\mathbb R^3$.  Again, when you choose the new ordering try and make the actions line up.  So if $S$ kills the first basis vector in $B$ then make sure $T$ kills the first basis vector in $C$.  If $S$ sends the $i^\text{th}$ basis vector of $B$ to the $j^\text{th}$ basis vector of $B$, then make sure that $T$ also sends the $i^\text{th}$ basis vector of $C$ to the $j^\text{th}$ basis vector of $C$.

Comment: I understand why my build is wrong, but I don't understand your hint... Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Notice each transformation sends a vector to $0$.  So start by saying that the first basis element in $B$ should be the vector $T$ sends to zero and the first basis element of $C$ should be the vector that $S$ sends to zero.

Comment: I did that and I still can't prove the statement... I always get a line of nulls in the representation matrix...

Comment: You can't calculate a representation matrix until you know the vectors in the basis.  I suspect this is the root of your misunderstanding on this problem.  I've added a further hint.

Comment: Jim, Thanks for your help! I assumed that B is the standard basis and calculated [S]_B$, then I found what should be C. I edited my first post, could you please share your thoughts? thanks again!